# Two "not only" with one "but"; What should I do?

Tags: redundancy, parallelism, multiple-negation

I found this in [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/belief/2010/jan/02/polygamy-polyandry)

> And assuming a 50:50 gender divide, polygamy *not only* means that women in polygamous relationships ***not only*** receive a small fraction of a man, *but* that some unfortunate men lower down the pecking order will get no woman at all.

I believe the above sentence has a grammatical mistake. There are two "**not only**" but has only one "**but**". If I make the sentence parallel, I have trouble in second **not only**, which is highlighted in bold. What should I do in this scenario?

How find some of the "**not only**" which does not follow with "**but**". In this condition how can I rephrase the sentence?

> And assuming a 50:50 gender divide, polygamy means *not only that* women in polygamous relationships ***not only*** receive a small fraction of a man, *but that* some unfortunate men lower down the pecking order will get no woman at all.

Comment: I didn't understand. Do you mean second sentence or second "not only"?

Comment: Second **only one**.

Comment: fine! If a sentence has one "not only" and does not have "but also" or an option to insert "but also", is that sentence incorrect. Or should it be rephrased?

Comment: By **redundant** I mean it's not necessary to have it. The sentence should be rephrased, in my idea. And I told you how we can change it.

Comment: @Sina -- Your comments would make a good answer.

Comment: @ARYF -- When you were taught the grammar rule (that you think this sentence breaks), were you taught any examples that were similar to this sentence?

Comment: @Jasper The problem is I am being taught by myself. That's why I am getting help from the website like ELL. Don't mistake me or my grammar.

Comment: @ARYF -- Thank you for your reply.  It helped me decide to remove the "grammar-myths" tag from this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second (emphasized) "not only" should be "only" to make it a logical sentence. It appears to be an editorial mistake.

For completion of the sentence, I personally perfer "but also" over "but" (although "but" is allowed according to credible sources, for example [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/not-only-but-also)). With a long sentence like this one, the idiomatically "but also" could help the reader.

Edit: Also, the verb "means" applied to both parts of the sentence, so it should be placed before "not only".

The result would be

> And assuming a 50:50 gender divide, polygamy *means not only* that women in polygamous relationships only receive a small fraction of a man, *but also* that some unfortunate men lower down the pecking order will get no woman at all.